# Dice odds: making a 7 before point, why are odds the number the same as a single roll?

Tags: probability

A 7 can be made six ways. Say one's point is 9 which can only be made four ways so the correct odds is 6:4. I understand that certainly for one roll this is correct but it is not obvious to me that over multiple rolls the odds remain 6:4.

What is a way to show this?

Answer (score 1):

You can assume, without loss of generality, that it will only take a finite number of rolls before you roll either a 7 or a 9.

Assume that it takes $~n~$ rolls.  Then, regardless of the value of $~n,~$ you have that on the first $~(n-1)~$ rolls, you did not roll either a 7 or a 9.  Then, these first $~(n-1)~$ rolls may be ignored, because just before the $~n$-th roll, the situation is exactly the same as it was, just before the first roll.

So, the probability of rolling a 7 before a 9, given that the first [7 or 9] is on roll $~n~$ is exactly the same as the probability of rolling a 7 before a 9, given that the first [7 or 9] is on the first roll.

That is, assuming that the first [7 or 9] is on roll $~n,~$ the relative probability of the roll being a $~7,~$ rather than a $~9,~$ is **independent of the value of** $~n.$

Let $~A~$ denote the event that on the $~1$-st roll, you rolled a $~7.~$

Let $~B~$ denote the event that on the $~1$-st roll, you rolled either a $~7~$ or a $~9.$

Then, you want $~p(A|B), ~$ which, by [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) is

$$\frac{p(A \cap B)}{p(B)} = \frac{6/36}{(6/36) + (4/36)}.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$

A *less intuitive* approach:

Let $~q = \frac{26}{36},~$ which equals the probability that a specific roll results in something other than a 7 or a 9.

The probability of rolling $~(n-1)~$ numbers, each other than a 7 or 9 is $~q^{(n-1)}.~$

So, you either rolled $~(n-1)~$ numbers other than a 7 or 9, and then rolled a 7, or you rolled $~(n-1)~$ numbers other than a 7 or 9, and then rolled a 9.

So, the probability that 7 occurred before 9 is

$$\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n-1}\right] \times \frac{6}{36}$$

$$= \left[1 + q + q^2 + \cdots\right] \times \frac{6}{36}$$

$$= \frac{1}{1-q} \times \frac{6}{36}$$

$$= \frac{1}{10/36} \times \frac{6}{36}$$

$$= \frac{36}{10} \times \frac{6}{36} = \frac{6}{10}.$$